# how to use <= sign in creating a function?

Tags: r

I have to solve this exercise question:

Create a function `ans(x, y, c)` which returns the value `c*x^2*y`, if 
`x^2 <= y <= 1`, and the value `0` otherwise.

I am using this command:

```
    ans<-function(x,y,c){
+ ifelse((x^2)<=y<=1, c*x^2*y, 0)}
```

but R is giving me this error:

```
Error: unexpected '<=' in:
```

Can someone help me to solve it please.

Comment: I would have doubts about the person who's teaching R and asking you to use `c` as a function argument

Comment: The error is here: `(x^2)<=y<=1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `&` to set two conditions in your function.

```
ans <- function(x, y, c){
  ifelse(x^2 <= y & y <= 1, c * x^2 * y, 0)
  }
```